# Simple memory game with replay button

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

I want to build a simple memory game. I want to put a replay button, which is play again the memory game.

I have built a class named `MemoryGame` and a main class.

Here is the part of the `ButtonListener` code.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        if (exitButton == e.getSource()) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
        else if (replayButton == e.getSource()) {
            //How can I declare it? 
        }
}
```

If I declare the replay button as :

```
new MemoryGame();
```

It's work fine, but it pops up another windows.

I want to clear the current display and return to the beginning, without a new windows. How can I do that?

EDIT :

I think I need to rewrite the code of my program, because my program does not have the `init()` method as suggested which is the initial state of the program.

My Java knowledge is very limited and usually I create less method and dump most into a method.

I will try to redo my program.

Thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: I would say make a method in MemoryGame that clears all progress and shuffles the cards and then starts playing again.

Comment: It sounds like you need to have the instance reset its state, and not call a new instance.  So your MemoryClass needs a new method like newGame that sets your state to when it was first called.

Comment: does your class extend JFrame?

Comment: Yes, my class is using extend JFrame. The code posted is just the part of the action for the button. So, what is the matter with `extend JFrame` ?

Comment: do you have your main method inside another class?

Comment: My main class is just plain main class. Here is the main function in the main class.
 
    `public static void main(String[] args) {
        new MemoryGame();
        }`

Comment: I added an example in my answer so that you can guide yourself or try it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show us what is inside the `MemoryGame` how you create its initial state. Effectively what folks are suggesting here is for you is to have an initial method which will set-up the game state which the `MemeoryGame` constructor will call. Then on replay-button of the game you call this method.

Something along these lines:

```
void init(){
   this.x = 10;
   this.y = 10;
}

public MemoryGame(){
   init();
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
   if (exitButton == e.getSource()) {
      System.exit(0);
   }
   else if (replayButton == e.getSource()) {
      init();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

one way you can do it although it might be dirty, is to grab your MemoryGame constructor, and put the stuff inside it inside another method, and call that method in your constructor and inside the button event.

as an example i have made the following class and it resets itself with the use of the previous technique:

```
public class App extends JFrame{

public static void main(String[] args){
    new App();
}

public App(){
    init();
}

private JButton changeColorButton;
private JButton resetAppButton;
private JPanel panel;

private void init() {
    changeColorButton=null;
    resetAppButton=null;
    panel=null;

    this.setSize(200,400);
    this.setVisible(true);
    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setBackground(Color.white);
    panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200,400));

    changeColorButton = new JButton("Change");
    changeColorButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            panel.setBackground(Color.black);
            panel.repaint();
        }
    });
    changeColorButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

    resetAppButton = new JButton("Reset");
    resetAppButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            init();
        }
    });
    resetAppButton.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,100));

    panel.add(changeColorButton);
    panel.add(resetAppButton);

    this.add(panel);

    this.validate();

}
}
```

what this app does is it has two buttons. one changes the color and the other resets the app itself.

Comment: thanks. i refined what i meant :) precicely what you meant. +rep

Comment: Very nice compact example. I like it (+1). A suggestion it is not necessary to create the objects each time you could do it with a boolean flag in the `init()` method and only create them initially. Or even better have a separate method doing GUI stuff that will only be run once from the `App` constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You should think about re-factoring your code so that the MemoryGame class does not create the GUI, then you wont be recreating it whenever you initialise a new Game.

It's a good idea to keep program logic separate to UI code.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is you could call dispose() on your JFrame. This will get rid of it and go to your title screen like this:

Here's the button code

```
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
    {

    if (closeButton = event.getSource())
    {

    System.exit(0);

    }

    if (playAgainButton = event.getSource())
    {

    Game.frame.dispose(); // Your class name, then the JFrame variable and call dispose

    }

    }
```

This will work but you may have a few problems reseting your program. If so then create a reset method where you can reset all your variables and call when playAgainButton is clicked. For example:

```
    public void reset()
    {

    // Right here you'd reset all your variables

    // Perhaps you have a gameOver variable to see if it's game over or not reset it

    gameOver = false;

    }
```